# Invite site vistors to share without an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm currently building a wordpress plugin with some of the functionality involving being able to broadacst some thing via social media... twitter and Facebook primarily. I used to be able to use http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php to allow someone to share something on their wall without me needing to supply an App ID, but it seems this is deprecated and no longer supported, so I suspect may well become unavailable at some point. As it is a wordpress plugin, I want the functionality to be absolutely plug and play, with no need for my plugins users to register an app in order to be able to use the plugin. Is there anyway I can get a logged in FB user to be able to post something to their wall for me without me using an app?

Answer (score 4):

The Facebook share button has been deprecated in favor of the like button, so they suggest that you use that instead. You can however still use share button, and i doubt it will go offline for a while.

The reference can be fount here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/
as well as an share extension implementation for Worpress here
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-share-new/

Reference for the like button is here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ if you want to give that a go instead.

Comment: but the code for the share button uses the AppID for one of my apps which I was hoping to avoid... though I guess I could default to one I registered just for the plugin and allowed my user to change it if they had one...

Comment: Could you maybe use a global AppID that you supply with the plugin, so that anyone who uses the plugin end up using that same AppID? I think that is the solution used by other general share plugins like AddThis and such.

Comment: I think that might be the route to take :-)

Comment: Just note that with an app id comes a domain.  You can set up aliases but said aliases have to be related to the domain.  I've had to set up two apps, one for production/staging, one for local development, because of this restriction.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think that restriction only applies to Graph API calls, and not to social plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above links to the share documentation which requires an AppID as noted in the comments. Here's the code I am using. I found something functional and modified it. Not sure how long they'll support this, but it works for me:

```
         $('.fbShareLink').click(function () {
            //url to share
            var u = location.href,
                //title to share
                t = document.title,
                //image to show
                i = 'http://example.com/images/myLogo.jpg',
                //generate the full url
                fullUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t)+'&i=' + encodeURIComponent(i);

            //open it in a new window
            window.open(fullUrl, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
            return false;
        });
```

Hopefully its obvious, but that snippet is using jquery to bind click to an element. Hope it will help anyone else who ends up on this page searching for what I was looking for!